# Unable to upload a csv file because of the date and time format

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery, format

i am Unable to upload a csv file because of the date and time format. If I try to open the CSV file before so I can fix the date column, it would not bring me the whole dataset , so i want to upload it into bigquery so i can fix the date time there

Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '4/12/2016 7:21:00 AM' as TIMESTAMP for field Time (position 1) starting at location 15 with message 'Invalid time zone: AM'

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Did you try to define a schema with the date time column as a string? My idea is, you can load the column as a string and then apply transformation to clean the data. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery accepts date in the format YYYY-MM-DD ([Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type))

Now to get the data first to BQ, load it in `STRING` field first in stage table and then put into the date format of your choice.
This way you don't have to open the file

Other tip is that BQ loads in all times in UTC. If you have data from some other local timezone, consider loading in `STRING` first and then in `DATETIME` field